# return all array if at least one element match

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

using the following array of arrays I need to do a search for an element, if it finds that element it should return the entire array it belongs to

example

```
const data= [[
      "car",
      "plane",
      "boat"
  ],
  [
      "paris",
      "barcelona",
      "los angeles"
  ],
  [
      "milk",
      "eggs",
      "brea",
  ]
]
```

if match car must return

```
[plane, boat]
```

if match paris must return

```
[barcelona, los angeles]
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+find+nested+array+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find/Filter will return the array(s)

```js
const data= [
  [ "car",   "plane",     "boat" ],
  [ "paris", "barcelona", "los angeles"],
  [ "milk",  "eggs",      "bread" ]
]
const findArr = (nestedArr, item) => nestedArr
  .find(arr => arr.includes(item))

const findAndExcludeItem = (nestedArr, item) => {
  const arrContaining = nestedArr.find(arr => arr.includes(item)) || []; // in case not found
  return arrContaining.filter(filteredItem => filteredItem != item);
};

const excludeArr = (nestedArr, item) => nestedArr
  .filter(arr => !arr.includes(item))



console.log(findArr(data,"paris"))
console.log(findAndExcludeItem(data,"paris"))
console.log(excludeArr(data,"paris"))
```

Comment: thanks, and to exclude the matching element, in this case paris?

Comment: Add `.filter(item => item!= "paris")` after `.flat()` to match the examples.

Comment: @RatajS then you will only get one long array

Comment: @FERNANDOORTIZ Added a function to return the found array but exclude the search element